# How to write unit test for BigQuery Java code

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, spring-test, test-coverage

Can you help me write the Java unit test cases for increasing the coverage for the below Java code which retrieves the data from the BigQuery using the given query ?

```java
BigQuery bigQueryInst =
                BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).setCredentials(googleCred.generateCred()).build()
                        .getService();

       
        String queryResp  = /* Query to be executed */;
     
        QueryJobConfiguration queryJobConfiguration =                     QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(carbonAgriRawDataRespQuery)
                .addPositionalParameter(QueryParameterValue.string(nodeID)).build();
      
        Job queryJob = bigQueryInst.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryJobConfiguration).build());
        queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();

        if (queryJob == null) {
            throw new Exception("Job no longer exists for Carbon Agriculture Raw Data");
        }

        if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
            throw new Exception(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
        }

        TableResult result = queryJob.getQueryResults();

        for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {

        }
```

I tried to mock the BigQuery instance, Job configuration instance, and Job instance using the key.json. But it resulted in a null pointer exception.

I am expecting a way to do the Unit Testing coverage for the mentioned Java code.